# Where can I specify init service conf for isc-dhcp-server?

Tags: server, dhcp, init

I used `service isc-dhcp-server start` to invoke the `dhcpd`. if I do `ps -ef | grep dhcp` here it is:

```
root@casalab-Latitude-D530:~# ps -ef | grep dhcp
dhcpd     6636     1  0 Apr28 ?        00:00:00 dhcpd
dhcpd     6640     1  0 Apr28 ?        00:00:00 dhcpd
dhcpd     6814     1  0 Apr28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/dhcpd -f -q -4 -pf /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid -cf /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
```

Where can I specify the server parameter and `dhcp.conf` file if I do it this way?

Answer (score 0):

The upstart job file (`/etc/init/isc-dhcp-server.conf`) sets the config file and the start parameters. This is the snippet of estimating the config file:

```
if [ -f /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf ]; then
  CONFIG_FILE=/etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf
else
  CONFIG_FILE=/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
fi
```

You can edit this lines to set your config file to your specified file.

And here the execute statement:

```
exec /usr/sbin/dhcpd -f -q -4 -pf /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid -cf $CONFIG_FILE $INTERFACES
```

Here, you can edit the parameters of the dhcpd daemon. After saving the file you can restart the dhcp service with the command:

```
service isc-dhcp-server restart
```

Comment: I found one under /etc/init/isc-dhcp-server.conf is it the correct one? Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Oh, sorry, I never mentioned the config file path=) Yes, it's that one. I edited my answer.